# Why can I not get num_rows in mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli

I can not understand why I do not get `num_rows` in mysqli.

Code:

```
$MysqlHost='localhost';
$MysqlUser='test';
$MysqlPassword='password';
$MysqlDatabase='test_data';


function mysqli($query){
  $mysqli = new mysqli($GLOBALS["MysqlHost"],$GLOBALS["MysqlUser"],$GLOBALS["MysqlPassword"],$GLOBALS["MysqlDatabase"]);
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Bad connect: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
  }
  $result = $mysqli->query("SET NAMES utf8");
  $result = $mysqli->query("set character_set_client='utf8'");
  $result = $mysqli->query("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");
  $result = $mysqli->query($query);
  $mysqli->error;
  $result->error;
  $mysqli->close();
  return $result;
};

$res_user=mysqli("SELECT * FROM table");
print $res_user->num_rows;
```

I get empty result, not `null(0)`, only empty...

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Closing the connection before you actually retrieve the result doesn't sound like a valid idea.

Comment: no no. function get finish $result before `mysqli->close()`;

Comment: You are requesting `num_rows` after you closed it. Take a look at my proposal.

Answer (score 0):

```
$MysqlHost='localhost';
$MysqlUser='test';
$MysqlPassword='password';
$MysqlDatabase='test_data';


function mysqli($query){
  $mysqli = new mysqli($GLOBALS["MysqlHost"],$GLOBALS["MysqlUser"],$GLOBALS["MysqlPassword"],$GLOBALS["MysqlDatabase"]);
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    return mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  else {
    $result = $mysqli->query("SET NAMES utf8");
    $result = $mysqli->query("set character_set_client='utf8'");
    $result = $mysqli->query("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    $err = $mysqli->error;
    $rrr = $result->error;
    $num = $result->num_rows;
    $mysqli->close();

    return Array($result, $num, $err, $rrr);
  }
};

$res_user=mysqli("SELECT * FROM table");
print $res_user->num_rows;
```

Something like this should work.

You should think a bit better about your approach to the connection variables.

Comment: You asked the question. We gave you our answer. I suggest you try it before you disregard it. We might just know a bit more then you do.